# Package trackchanges: problem with UTF8

Tags: unicode, incompatibility, trackchanges

the package `trackchanges` doesn't seem to work with utf8 encoding. Did somebody encounter the same problem? Does anybody have a solution ?

**Minimal example** :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{trackchanges}
\begin{document}
    text \remove{öäü}
\end{document}
```

The compilation error :

```
 ! Argument of \UTFviii@two@octets has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.6 text \remove{öäü}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
```

Wit oau instead of öäü, it works of course.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. "Does not work" doesn't give much information. What error do you get exactly?

Comment: Also check out the similar package [`latexdiff`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexdiff).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that loading the package `soulutf8` before `trackchanges` solves the problem

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{trackchanges}
\begin{document}
    text \remove{öäü}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even loading it afterwards seems to work.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be an issue of the internally used `soul` package (Strike-Out, UnderLine) used for highlighting of the changes. It reads the content stepwise and splits the Unicode characters in two. You might find help in the `soul` manual.

As a workaround I would redefine the used highlighting macros, e.g. `\stcolor` for the given example. Here I use a simple `\textcolor` (from the already loaded `xcolor` package) instead of the `soul` code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{trackchanges}
\renewcommand{\stcolor}[2]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}
\begin{document}
    text \remove{öäü}
\end{document}
```

This works for me.

Comment: Fine ! it seems to be a good workaround. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very late answer:
The package `soul` has problems with Umlauts.
Use the package `ulem` and its function `uline` instead of `ul` from `soul` and it should work.